# How to make only the last few characters show in a CharField for a django model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a model with a secret key field:

```
class Settings(model.Models):
   secret_key = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

I do not want this field to be seen publicly.
How do I make only the last few characters show and star out or hide the rest.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a method in your `Settings` model to return a masked version of the `secret_key`. For example:

```py
class Settings(models.Model):
    secret_key = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def get_masked_secret_key(self):
        length_to_show = 4
        mask_char = '*'
        
        visible_part = self.secret_key[-length_to_show:]
        masked_chars = mask_char * (len(self.secret_key) - length_to_show)
        
        return f'{masked_chars}{visible_part}'
```

```py
setting = Settings.objects.create(secret_key=”my_secret_key”)

print(setting.get_masked_secret_key())
```

This way, the method has fixed values for `length_to_show` and `mask_char`, and you can adjust them directly within the method if needed.